# Add a delay to Progress Dialog

Tags: android, delay, progressdialog

I want to make a dummy progress dialog appear for 2 or 3 seconds.  It won't actually do anything other than say detecting.  I have the code:

```
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Detecting...",
            true);
    dialog.show();

    dialog.dismiss();
```

But what do I put in between the show, and the dismissal to have the dialog appear for a few seconds?  Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The correct way - it does not block your main thread, so UI stays responsive:

```
dialog.show();

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}, 3000); // 3000 milliseconds delay
```

Comment: Great answer, just you are missing an additional curly brace before the last line:
}    }, 3000);  // 3000 miliseconds

Comment: excuse me! how we can update our message on progress dialog while waiting. for example:
5 sec...
4 sec...
3 sec...
2 sec...
1 sec...
BOOOOM! and dismiss

Answer (score 3):

```
        progress.setProgress(100);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pdialog.dismiss();
            }}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `CountDownTimer` of Android which is much more efficient than any other solution posted and it also support ***fires on regular interval*** through its `onTick()` method.

Have a look at this example,

```
 new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             // You don't need anything here
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need, Hanlder funtion can not use in Leanback :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        dialog.setMessage("Preparing resources...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
           Thread.sleep(3000);
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing comes between dismiss and show.. the time depending upon you. For example dialog will show before server access and it will dismiss getting result means

```
 dialog.show();
 ServerCall();
 dialog.close();
```

If you need empty delay means then use CountDownTimer call between that..

Answer (score 0):

In case some one looking for `Xamarin.Android` (*using C#*) solution (*of [Peter Knego's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209385/3367974)*), here is how:

```
new Handler().PostDelayed(() => { 
    dialog.dismiss();
}, 1000);
```