# loop, words and images in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, for-loop

My problem is this:
I enter text in a EditText and then display each of the individual letters, but that can be displayed using 2 ImageView.
I have no problems with ImageView, the problem is when you enter the word into the for, try to make a delay to show the first letter and continue with the others, but it does not work and just send me the last letter of the word you enter

The code:

```
public class deletreo extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    EditText etxt;
    ImageView img,img2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.deletreo);

        tv = new TextView(this);
        etxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                letra();

            }   
        });



    }//fin bundle





     public void letra()  {

         String t = "";

        t = etxt.getText().toString();
        String l = t.toLowerCase();
        int p = l.length();


            try{
                for( int j = 0 ; j < p ; j++){


                    if(l.charAt(j) == 'a' || l.charAt(j) == 'A'){
                        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.aa);
                        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);

                    }

                        if(l.charAt(j) == 'b' || l.charAt(j) == 'B'){
                            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb);
                            img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_2);

                        }
                            if(l.charAt(j) == 'c' || l.charAt(j) == 'C'){
                                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cc);
                                img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_3);

                            }
                                if(l.charAt(j) == 'd' || l.charAt(j) == 'D'){
                                    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dd);
                                    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_4);
                                }
                                    if(t.charAt(j) == 'e' || t.charAt(j) == 'E'){
                                        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ee);
                                        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_5);
                                    }
                                        if(t.charAt(j) == 'f' || t.charAt(j) == 'F'){
                                            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ff);
                                            img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_6);
                                        }
                                            if(t.charAt(j) == 'g' || t.charAt(j) == 'G'){
                                                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gg);
                                                img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_7);
                                            }
                                                if(t.charAt(j) == 'h' || t.charAt(j) == 'H'){
                                                    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.hh);
                                                    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_8);
                                                }
                                                    if(t.charAt(j) == 'i' || t.charAt(j) == 'I'){
                                                        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ii);
                                                        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_9);
                                                    }
                                                        if(t.charAt(j) == 'j' || t.charAt(j) == 'J'){
                                                            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.jj);
                                                            img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_10);
                                                        }
                                                            if(t.charAt(j) == 'k' || t.charAt(j) == 'K'){
                                                                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.kk);
                                                                img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_11);
                                                            }
                                                                if(t.charAt(j) == 'l' || t.charAt(j) == 'L'){
                                                                    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ll);
                                                                    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_12);
                                                                }
                                                                    if(t.charAt(j) == 'm' || t.charAt(j) == 'M'){
                                                                        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.mm);
                                                                        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_13);
                                                                    }
                                                                        if(t.charAt(j) == 'n' || t.charAt(j) == 'N'){
                                                                            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nn);
                                                                            img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_14);
                                                                        }
                                                                            if(t.charAt(j) == 'ñ' || t.charAt(j) == 'Ñ'){
                                                                                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nini);
                                                                                img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_15);
                                                                            }
                                                                                if(t.charAt(j) == 'o' || t.charAt(j) == 'O'){
                                                                                    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.oo);
                                                                                    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_16);
                                                                                }
                                                                                    if(t.charAt(j) == 'p' || t.charAt(j) == 'P'){
                                                                                        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pp);
                                                                                        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_17);
                                                                                    }
                                                                                        if(t.charAt(j) == 'q' || t.charAt(j) == 'Q'){
                                                                                            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.qq);
                                                                                            img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_18);
                                                                                        }
                                                                                            if(t.charAt(j) == 'r' || t.charAt(j) == 'R'){
                                                                                                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.rr);
                                                                                                img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_19);
                                                                                            }
                                                                                                if(t.charAt(j) == 's' || t.charAt(j) == 'S'){
                                                                                                    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ss);
                                                                                                    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_20);
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                    if(t.charAt(j) == 't' || t.charAt(j) == 'T'){
                                                                                                        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tt);
                                                                                                        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_21);
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                        if(t.charAt(j) == 'u' || t.charAt(j) == 'U'){
                                                                                                            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.uu);
                                                                                                            img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_22);
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                            if(t.charAt(j) == 'v' || t.charAt(j) == 'V'){
                                                                                                                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.vv);
                                                                                                                img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_23);
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                if(t.charAt(j) == 'w' || t.charAt(j) == 'W'){
                                                                                                                    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ww);
                                                                                                                    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                                    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_24);
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                    if(t.charAt(j) == 'x' || t.charAt(j) == 'X'){
                                                                                                                        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.xx);
                                                                                                                        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_25);
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                        if(t.charAt(j) == 'y' || t.charAt(j) == 'Y'){
                                                                                                                            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yy);
                                                                                                                            img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                                            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_26);
                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                            if(t.charAt(j) == 'z' || t.charAt(j) == 'Z'){
                                                                                                                                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                                                                                                                                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.zz);
                                                                                                                                img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                                                                                                                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_27);

                                                                                                                            }

                            Thread.sleep(2000);                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                }//fin del for

            }//fin try

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{}


     }//fin letra();



}//fin
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you use a debugger (or even log statements) to narrow the problem down some?

Comment: For your giant cascading `if/else` statement you should use a `switch` statement. It will be both cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: that it is, just where are the code if it is only to compare the letters entered in the EditText and I have not even changed by switch to something serious

Answer (score 1):

Down the bottom of the `for` loop you call:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

This will simply block the UI thread for 2 seconds. Since the UI thread is basically the life line of your application, above statement will halt *all* execution of code. The code outside the loop cannot magically continue running if you block the main thread and that's why your UI doesn't update after each iteration.

In stead of directly interacting with threads, it's probably easier to post a delayed `Runnable` to a `Handler` or use some other mechanism that emulates 'ticks' (e.g. `Timer`, `TimerTask` and `CountDownTimer` come to mind). With every tick you can then show the next character.

Comment: i tried as follows:

public void letra()  {
     
      String t = "";
      
  t = etxt.getText().toString();
  String l = t.toLowerCase();
     int p = l.length();
     
     
   try{
    for( int j = 0 ; j < p ; j++){if(l.charAt(j) == 'a' || l.charAt(j) == 'A'){
      img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
      img.setImageResource(R.drawable.aa);
      img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
      img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);
      
     }Thread.sleep(2000);
   }//fin try
   catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally{}
     }//fin letra

Comment: @DiegoF: Sorry, but I have no idea what changed in the (rather messy) code in your comment. I can still see `Thread.sleep(2000)` though, which is really what you should be getting rid of.

Comment: sorry I thought it might look good, I've done it at the end of the for loop is put the Thread.sleep (2000) to pause for 2 seconds so it does not work and is what I try to do

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding me correctly: you should **not** use `Thread.sleep()` as in the current setup it will block everything else. Please have a look at [implementing a `Handler`](http://goo.gl/8NS4S) or do a search for the other classes mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Got it, had missed your point, I'll try some of those mentioned and I will respond again, thanks

Comment: I updated my code and the result is still the same, only shows the last letter of the word and not make the delay, any ideas? I used Timer and TimerTask

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to put this action in a separate thread, and then use a `Handler` to pause and resume this new thread you've just created. This is done so that you're not freezing the main UI thread, which is what stuff on Android runs on by default.

I googled 'android add delay inbetween changes' and got a bunch of results, one of which is this: [Add a delay to Progress Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209270/add-a-delay-to-progress-dialog)

Also, use a `switch` statement instead of your giant cascading `if/else` statements. It will make your code a whole heck of a lot cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Would someone like to tell me why I was wrong instead of just downvoting me? It doesn't help me, and it doesn't help the OP.

Comment: I've tried the way you suggest, making a separate thread, and I get the same result I tried with 4 different ways of Thread and I can not work

Comment: Well then you're doing it wrong. Google 'how to multi-thread in android'.

Comment: I updated my code and the result is still the same, only shows the last letter of the word and not make the delay, any ideas? I used Timer and TimerTask